# Should I have to close used cursor by ContentResolver?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-cursor

For example, given the following code:

```
Cursor myCursor = context.getContentResolver()
    .query(MediaStore.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);`
```

Do I have to close "myCursor"?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you need to always close the cursor once your work is done with it.

Comment: @Grishu - Not if you use [`CursorAdapter#changeCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor(android.database.Cursor)) ;) Generally speaking, though, yes.

Comment: Thanks to reply. Then, even if have to close used cursor by CursorLoader?

Comment: In last case (CursorLoader), you don't need but make sure to call Cursor.swap(null) to unregister observers.

Answer (score 2):

Cursors should always be closed in some way to avoid memory leaks. However, if you are implementing `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` then overriding the following method closes the cursor for you.

```
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```